# WCF ReceiveContext

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a task where I'm trying to insure delivery of data to a database in the order in which it is written.  The database will be located on another machine, and it's possible that the database machine could fail while the sending computer continues to queue up database messages.

I'm trying to use WCF for this task and from my initial reading believed that this might be possible using WCF with message queue and a ReceiveContext enabled channel.  The documentation states that ReceiveContext 'enables an application to decide whether to access the message or leave it in the queue for further processing.'

The problem that I've encountered is that if I call the Abandon method indicating that the message has not been successful processed and should be left on the queue, WCF appears to place the message at the back of the queue instead of leaving it at the front of the queue.  Since I need to write the messages to the database in the order they were originally sent this solution will not work.

Is there any way to force WCF to 'peek' at a message before removing it or cause an abandon message to be placed at the front of the queue?  If not could anyone suggest a method of accomplishing what I'm attempting to do without having to write a lot of code from scratch.

Thanks,
   Al

Comment: Maybe you could use [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't want to just peek and then decide, isn't the correct method to transactionally requeue the message?